# JavaFX - How to pass data from a class to a controller

Tags: java, javafx

This is my current project structure:

```
guiPackage
    Window
    WindowController

mainPackage
    Main
```

The Main class handles my main program and logic (in main method).

The Window class is just a basic window with a label.

How would I update the label text from my Main class? I assume I need to access the controller and pass data to it.

Is this the correct structure for a JavaFX project or is there a better way of doing things?

Edit: This is the code from my main method:

```
    Window.launch(Window.class);

    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(Viewer.class.getResource("/gui/fxml/Viewer.fxml"));
    ViewerController controller = fxmlLoader.getController();
    controller.setLabelText("Test");
```

This doesn't appear to change the label text at all.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml/14190310#14190310

Comment: I've followed that tutorial with no luck. See my edit above.

Comment: You have to call `getController()` after you call `load()` (since the controller is defined in the FXML file, the loader won't know its controller until it's loaded the file...). Also, this should not be in your `main(...)` method, since that isn't on the FX Application Thread. You should really think of the `start(...)` method in your application class as the replacement for the `main(...)` method in a "regular" Java application; perhaps just move your application logic from `main(...)` to `start(...)`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Why shouldn't this be in the main method? The main method is where my main program is - how else would I transfer data from the Main class to the Window class? Should I instead move everything from main method to the Window class? Wouldn't that defeat the point of separating logic from GUI?

Comment: I just read your edit, thanks. I'll move everything from the main method to the Window `start(...)` method and give this another go.

Comment: You can still separate things, but use the `start(...)` method as the launch point instead of the `main(..)` method. Neither one should contain much code, no matter what the application.